# How to go by this, to solve for X with matrix equation (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix}-3 & -5\\-8 & 6\end{bmatrix}X + \begin{bmatrix}-8 & 3\\-3 & 6\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}4 & 9\\-6 & 8\end{bmatrix}X$$

I'm really unsure how to do this number? That's stumping me is the second location of X

much appreciative for any help,
cheers

Comment: Welcome to math SE. If $X$ is a $2\times2$ matrix, just do the multiplication and you'll end up with 4 equations with 4 unknowns.

Comment: It is just like a normal equation $Ax + B = Cx$ - rearrange to collect the $x$ terms like $(A-C)x = - B$ and then solve as normal, multiplying by the inverse of $A-C$ if you are lucky enough that it is invertible (and if I subtracted right, it is).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Your matrix equation is essentially of the form $$AX + B = CX$$ You can subtract $CX$ and $B$ from both sides and factor to obtain $$(A-C)X = -B$$

Comment: Thank you! Once I get there, how do I solve for X?

Comment: Well, if $A-C$ is invertible, you could multiple both sides on the left by its inverse. Then $X = (A-C)^{-1}(-B)$.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your steps and got X =  $$\begin{bmatrix}-13/7 & 39/7\\5/14 & -18/7\end{bmatrix}$$